# Redirect multiple URLs (number included in URL) to the same new one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have 3 URLs like:

```
http://example.com/archives/2001_2005/
http://example.com/archives/2006/
http://example.com/archives/2007/
```

How to use .htaccess to 301-redirect all of them to:

```
http://example.com/archives/2001-2007/
```

I tried this below but it doesn't work (I prefer with as simple one line as posssible):

```
RewriteRule ^archives/(2001_2005|2006|2007) http://example.com/archives/2001-2007/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is RewriteEngine On?

Comment: Is it in a VirtualHost or Directory section?

Comment: Yes, everything is set up with the server correctly. With my example/solution, there is 410 status (gone) and no redirection takes place. When doing separate redirections, like: redirect 301 /archives/2006/ http://example.com/archives/2001-2007/ it works correctly. But I'd like a simpler rule that covers everything in one line..

Comment: What about using **ErrorDocument 410 /archives/2001-2007**, which will route requests for content that has been removed to the new URL? Instead of using Rewrites.

Comment: It would be even more complicated and around, I'd like the simpler solution to redirect if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RedirectMatch :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/archives/(2001_2005|2006|2007) http://example.com/archives/2001-2007
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.